# Display input title only "onclick" event

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble in displaying my title input only "onclick" event.
When we mouseouver the input box, it will display the title, but i just want this to happen when I click on the input box.

My idea is displaying a title saying "value copied", cause I have a function on "onclick" event that copy the input (read only) value to the clipboard, and when it's done I want to let the user know that this happen displaying that information.
Is that even possible?
(this is for a windows gadget)

Thank you to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.focus()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>span {display:none;}</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p><input type="text" /> <span>focus fire</span></p>
<p><input type="password" /> <span>focus fire</span></p>
<script>
$("input").focus(function () {
  $(this).next("span").css('display','inline').fadeOut(1000);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: God bless you, I solved this issue (maybe in a messy way), using "onclick" to set the input title to "Value copied" and "onmouseout" to set the title to "". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I decided to use Jquery (it's much better), the other method was bugged. Once again, thank you.