# Show input title tooltip on click (not hover)

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I am using the title attribute to show a tooltip for a number input field. It works well, but this code is intended for mobile use so therefore the tooltip needs to show when the input field is clicked, rather than hovered over.

Here is an example of how the tooltip is currently displayed when hovered over:

```html
<input title ="This should only show when input is clicked" type="number" id="price" value=1.80>
```

Is it possible to display a title tooltip on click, rather than on hover?

Comment: do you mean on `focus` ?

Comment: Yes, focus. Sorry I am still new to this :)

Comment: see this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259587/display-input-title-only-onclick-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use an info icon image and combine it with the tooltip function from an awesome library called [jBox](https://stephanwagner.me/jBox/get_started).

HTML

```
src="https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/info.png" class="myTooltip" title="I am a tooltip!" width="22px" height="auto">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    new jBox('Tooltip', {
      attach: '.myTooltip',
      trigger: 'click',  
      position: {    
          y: 'bottom'
          },  
      });
});
```

[See this CodePen for a working demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMXOoL)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without jQuery:

```js
function showTooltip() {
  document.getElementById("price").title = "This should only show when input is clicked";
}

function removeTooltip() {
  document.getElementById("price").title = "";
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="price" value="1.80" onfocus="showTooltip()" onfocusout="removeTooltip()" />
```

Comment: Hi Vic. This doesn't seem to work for me. Once the input has been focused, the tooltip doesn't appear until you move your mouse out of the input field, and then hover back over it. Here is the example - https://codepen.io/JonoGIS/pen/bxgLVV

Comment: I see, you only get the tooltip if you move your mouse. It may be needed to make your own tooltip so you have more control over it. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp

Comment: Take a look at my answer, jBox did the trick! Thanks for your help though :)