# Simple way to show tooltip on click rather than hover

Tags: html, qualtrics

I am working a survey in Qualtrics. The following HTML code allows me to show the tooltip text "Text describing this concept" when the user hovers over the text "risk of negative societal effects from climate change and SG deployment (if any) in 2050 and in 2100."

```
<i>Please complete the following sentences related to how other factors impact the <span title="Text describing this concept"> <b>risk of negative societal effects from climate change and SG deployment (if any) in 2050 and in 2100.</b></span> </i>
```

Is there a simple way to change this so that the tooltip text only appears when they user clicks on the text? By simple, I mean without adding a bunch of css or other code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945550/show-input-title-tooltip-on-click-not-hover

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show input title tooltip on click (not hover)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945550/show-input-title-tooltip-on-click-not-hover)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this purely with CSS, which have different UX considerations.

Using `:active` with a parent-child relationship (i.e. when the `b` element is actively being mouse-downed upon.) This has accessibility issues for obvious reasons.

```css
span{
  visibility: hidden;
}
b:active > span{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<i>Please complete the following sentences related to how other factors impact the  <b>risk of negative societal effects from climate change and SG deployment (if any) in 2050 and in 2100. <span title="Text describing this concept">tooltip text</span></b> </i>
```

Using `input:checked`, which requires hiding an `input` of type `checkbox` and using a `label` to affect its state.

```css
span{
  display: none;
}

input{
  appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
}

input:checked ~ span{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<i>Please complete the following sentences related to how other factors impact the <input type="checkbox" id="tooltip"><span title="Text describing this concept">tool tip</span> <label for="tooltip"><b>risk of negative societal effects from climate change and SG deployment (if any) in 2050 and in 2100.</b></label> </i>
```

You could then style the label when focused on the checkbox to help with tab navigation.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. The second option is close, but when I run the code snippet and click on the text, I do not see "Text describing this concept", but rather "tool tip".

Comment: Yeah, because it's not content inside of the `<span>`. If you want the CSS to interpret what you have inside of title, you'll want to use a custom `data-attribute` and print the content of the attribute with `content` inside of a `::before` or `::after`. You can't use the native `title` with click/on-click functionality as it is browser-rendered.